# Algorithm of bidirectional graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I've got a graph (or unrooted tree) of `N nodes` and `N-1 connections`. Each connection has a `distance of 1`.

How can i find a node **v** that has the maximum distance between **v** and a set of nodes **E{}**, when **v** can be a node in **E**?

**Constraints:**

- (N <= 50000)
- Number of node in E <= N
- Time limit 1 s

Comment: How do you define the distance between `v` and `E` -- minimum, average, maximum? The usual definition of a metric on a graph is between two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) starting with the node set `E`.  `v` will then be the last node you visit.

**Edit:**

```
1-2-3-4    E={1,4,5}
    |
    5
```

Ok, now I understand your metric.  You want to compute, for each edge, the total sum of distances from that edge to the elements of `E` on either side of that edge.  You can do that by computing the values up from the leaves to the root (handwaving a bit).

Then you can compute for each node the sum of those values on each incoming edge.  Pick the node with the biggest sum.

Comment: I do not think that this will be enough. For some weird trees, v could actually be *inside* of E, i.e. the mean distance of some node in E to all the other nodes in E can be greater than the mean distance of all the nodes not in E to the nodes in E.

Comment: @tobias_k: I don't see what mean distance has to do with anything.  BFS does not visit a node twice, so once you've started your BFS with all of `E`, you'll never visit `E` nodes again.

Comment: @Keith Randall 
one counter example:
1--2--3--4
      |
      5 with N=5 and E={1,4,5}

the answer is in E{}, which is 1
but if we do BFS in all node we'll get 2 or 3,which is the wrong answer

Comment: i.e. 3 is connected with 4 and 5

Comment: @user195872: I'm confused.  2 (or 3) seems like the right answer to me.  The distance between 1,4, and 5 to E is 0.  The distance from 2 and 3 to E is 1.  Perhaps you should better describe the metric you're going for.  I was finding a `v` such that `min(d(v,x) for x in E)` is maximal, where `d(x,y)` is the minimum distance between x and y in the graph.  What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear problem
Let me restate "How can i find a node v,that has the maximum distance between v and a set of nodes E{}" as "How can i find a node v,that has the maximum "sum of"distance between v and all nodes in nodes E{}"

Comment: Using the example above,E={1,4,5}, 
assume d(a,b) be the distance between a and b
d(1,1)=0
d(1,4)=3
d(1,5)=3
so if we select node 1 ,the sum of distance is 6,which is the maximum

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is acyclic you can make the edge weights -1 and run Floyd-Warshall. This will give you all-pairs longest path. Then for each node in the graph take the average distance to the nodes in E.

Otherwise I believe looking at an NP-Complete problem of trying to find the longest path in an arbitrary graph.

Comment: I think that Floyd-Warshall is far too slow from solving(O(N^3)) 
I need a O(N lg N) or even faster solution

Comment: Floyd Warshall is more appropriate (designed for) for dense graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm to compute the distance of every node from each vertex of `E`.

The graph is a tree, and initially un-rooted.

1. Arbitrarily pick a node as the root
2. Traverse the tree, and compute for each node, the number of vertices in its subtree that are in `E` (we can call this function `e(node)`).

   - For example, if your tree is as follows (where the brackets show the vertices in `E={C,D,I}`), you will compute the numbers as shown:

     ```
     vertices in the graph:              e(v)

               A                          3
              / \                        / \
             B  (C)                     1   2
            / \   \                    / \   \
          (D)  F   G                  1   0   1
          /         \                /         \
         H          (I)             0           1
     ```
3. Also calculate the distance of the root node from the set `E` (call this function `d(v)`). We see `d(A)=6`, and is easily calculated while traversing the tree in step 2.
4. Then, traverse the tree again, to compute the distance function of each node, where the formula is `d(v) = d(parent(v)) + size(E) - 2*e(v)`. This will take `O(n)` time for all nodes, because it is constant time for each node.

   The formula is derived by considering that when you move from a parent to a child, the distance from the set of nodes in `E` changes by:

   - an increase in distance by 1 for each nodes in `E` *not* in the subtree of the child
   - a decrease in distance by 1 for each node in `E` which is also in the subtree of the child

   **Examples:**

   - `d(B) = d(A) + size(E) - 2*e(B) = 6 + 3 - 2 = 7`,
   - `d(D) = d(B) + size(E) - 2*e(D) = 7 + 3 - 2 = 8`,
   - `d(H) = d(D) + size(E) - 2*e(H) = 8 + 3 - 0 = 11`,
   - `d(F) = d(B) + size(E) - 2*e(F) = 7 + 3 - 0 = 10`
5. Then just search the node `v` which has the highest `d(v)`, you can do this by traversing the tree again. You can also do this at the same time that you traverse the tree in the step 4.

This algorithm requires only 2 distinct traversals of the tree, each taking `O(n)` time. Thus, the overall algorithmic complexity is `O(n)`.

Note that the reason this algorithm can be so efficient is that the graph is a **tree**. Most shortest path algorithms are for general graphs. A tree is much simpler in that there is only one unique path between any pair of vertices. Thus, there is no need for the tactics generally required in shortest path algorithms.